# Project raster file using GCP's

Tags: gdal, reprojection-error

I have a projected tiff file from sentinel1 data (s1a-ew-grd-hh-20180208t071218-20180208t071323-020512-023164-001.tiff) (lets call it test.tiff) with the following projection in WKT format:

```
PROJCS["WGS 84",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Polar_Stereographic"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",70],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-45],PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
```

This should be equivalent to the Arctic Polar Stereographic (epsg 3995). My goal is to slightly tune the image by inserting some GCP's and warp it. To double check this method I am starting with the trivial case, where I get the corner coordinates from the projected image (test.tiff):

```
Size is 17959, 18039
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  457598.467, -240151.021) ( 17d18'33.06"E, 85d13'55.33"N)
Lower Left  (  457598.467,-1142101.021) ( 23d 9'56.93"W, 78d40'39.65"N)
Upper Right ( 1355548.467, -240151.021) ( 34d57'13.08"E, 77d20'28.88"N)
Lower Right ( 1355548.467,-1142101.021) (  4d53' 4.53"E, 73d44'33.76"N)
Center      (  906573.467, -691126.021) (  7d40'47.73"E, 79d30'17.56"N)
```

and I set the GCP according to that. Hence:

```
gdal_translate -gcp 0.0 0.0 457598.467 -240151.021 -gcp 0.0 18039.0 1355548.467 -240151.021 -gcp 17959.0 18039.0 1355548.467 -1142101.021 -gcp 17959.0 0.0 457598.467 -1142101.021 -a_srs WKT_PROJECTION test.tiff gcp.tiff
```

Then I warp the image using the -tps option to force warping using the GCP information.

```
gdalwarp -tps gcp.tiff gcp_warped.tiff
```

One would expect that the test.tiff and the gcp_warped.tiff files should coincide which is unfortunately not the case:

[image]

Is there something that I miss during the above mentioned procedure? Or is there another work around?